# elements in list not staying together on resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, html-lists

I posted this a little earlier but deleted it because I was able to figure a little of it out. Im having an issue when resizing a screen with this todo list project im working on. Im using a bit of javascript that creates a list item every entry. The person types in a todo task and then a check box and remove icon is added. My issue is that on smaller screens, the checkbox and remove icon is jumping up a layer when a long named task is given. Im using bootstrap 4 to hold it all in place on my html side. My image should help clarify what I'm talking about. I think the javascript may be the issue.

Here is the list when on a medium screen. Looks correct with the checkbox/trash icon being to the right of the item.
[image]

Here is the issue when the screen gets smaller. The checkbox/trash icon goes up a line as the text breaks down. How can I make it stay on the first line as the text? Ive tried setting the "li" element to width="90%;" with the checkbox/remove icon taking up the remaining 10. It looks worse then. I'm really not sure. Ill attach the relevant code.
[image]

```js
function show() {
 var todos = get_todos();
 
 var html = '<ul>';
 for(var i=0; i < todos.length; i++) {
     html += '<span><input class="checkBox" type="checkbox"><li style="float:left;">' + todos[i] + '</li>' + '<button class="remove" id="' + i  + '"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></span><br/>';
 };
 html += '</ul>';
 
 document.getElementById('todos').innerHTML = html;
 
 var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
 for (var i=0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
     buttons[i].addEventListener('click', remove);
 };
}
```

```css
   body, html { /*makes the background image stretch the whole screen*/
 height:100%;
}
 body {
 background-image:url('campingBackground.jpg');
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-attachment:fixed;
 background-position:center;
 background-size:cover;
}
 .checkBox {
 margin-right:10px;
 height:18px;
 width:18px;
}
 .checkBox:hover {
 background-color:#C0C0C0; 
}
   .remove { /*Trash can button*/
 color:white;
 font-size:24px;
 border:0;
 padding:0;
 background-color:transparent;
}
 .remove:hover {
 color:#C0C0C0;
}
 ul {
 text-align:right; /*This pushes the checkbox/trash can right while the <li> in the js file floats the todo text left*/
 list-style-type:none;
 padding-left:0px; /*Makes up for not having the bullet point spacing on smaller screens*/ 
 font-size:24px;
 color:white;
 font-weight:600;
}
 li {
 text-align:left;
}
```

```html
 <div class="header">
  <div class="container" style="padding-top:50px;"> 
   <div class="row justify-content-center"> <!--Input Box-->
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-8">
     <h1>To-Do List</h1>
     <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="task">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row"> <!--Add Button-->
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="margin-right:15px; margin-top:30px;">
     <button id="add" style="border-radius:50%; font-size:35px; width:65px;" class="btn btn-danger">+</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
  <div class="container text"> <!--ToDos-->
   <div class="row justify-content-center" style="margin-top:20px;"> 
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-8">
     <div id="todos"></div>
    </div> 
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you tell what the screen size does the problem start with?

Comment: it brakes down to two lines @ 767px. That is probably just because that is the length of my longer task "finishing packing before going to airport at 8:15". If I had a task that was twice as long, it would break at an earlier point and if I had one smaller, it would break later.@Dmitry S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, having an `ul` list with items like `span` as child nodes is not correct, according to the [HTML Specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element) for a list (`ul`) element:

> The ul element represents a list of items, where the order of the items is not important — that is, where changing the order would not materially change the meaning of the document.
>
> The items of the list are the li element child nodes of the ul element.

The problem is given because according to the name of the `todo` item, there is no space for the `todo` to fit.

I recommend this changes to your code as a possible solution:

```js
var todos = [
  'Lorem ipsun dolor sit amet',
  'Answer a question related to JavaScript on StackOverflow',
  'Another todo',
  'A really long long todo to show this code working for todo with long long long names'
];

var html = '<ul>';
for(var i=0; i < todos.length; i++) {
    html += '<li class="todo-item">' + 
          '<span class="todo-label">' + todos[i] + '</span>' +
          '<input class="checkBox" type="checkbox">' +
          '<button class="remove" id="' + i  + '">' + 
          '<i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + 
          '</button>' +
      '</li>';
};

html += '</ul>';

document.write(html);
```

```css
/* https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_clearfix.asp */
.todo-item::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;  
}

.todo-item {
  text-align: right;
}

.todo-item .todo-label {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  max-width: 80%; /*  you can increase the size */
  text-align: left;
  /* you can use this props if you don't wan another line */
  /* white-space: nowrap; */
  /* text-overflow: ellipsis; */
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  
}
```

Comment: So this is really helpful but there is one thing I left out that I now see isnt quite working right. I have this line of css that doesnt work when things are shifted around. ` input:checked + li {
 text-decoration:line-through;
 max-width:90%;
}
`Basically what this does is put a line through the list item when its corresponding checkbox is checked. This is helpful for people that want to acknowledge that they did something on their list but dont want to delete it so they can still reference that they did it. Im trying to see if I can get it working again. I think its the order.